# How to get the minor number of a file in a Linux driver?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Is there a better solution to get the minor number?

Can I avoid checking kernel version?

```
static long unlocked_ioctl(struct file *f, unsigned int o, unsigned long d)
{
#if KERNEL_VERSION(3, 18, 0) > LINUX_VERSION_CODE
    struct inode* inode = f->f_dentry->d_inode;
#else
    struct inode* inode = f->f_path.dentry->d_inode;
#endif

    int minor = iminor(inode);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for minor or major number? The title ask for minor number and the code snippet manages the major numbers.

Comment: Is there a reason for putting together two unrelated questions?

Comment: @RachidK - I'm asking for the minor(actually it does not matter, both of them arrives from inode)

Comment: @stark - I don't see two unrelated questions, just asked for how to retrieve the minor number.

Comment: Hi @Roi, I don't want to avoid this checking, just asking if there is a better solution to get the minor number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a better way: don't bother looking at the `dentry` when what you want is right there as a field of `struct file`.

```c
struct file {
    union {
        struct llist_node   fu_llist;
        struct rcu_head     fu_rcuhead;
    } f_u;
    struct path     f_path;
    struct inode    *f_inode; // <-- here's your inode
    // ...
}
```

You can either access `f->f_inode` directly or use the [`file_inode()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.18/source/include/linux/fs.h#L1888) function, this way you can also avoid kernel version checks.

```c
static long unlocked_ioctl(struct file *f, unsigned int o, unsigned long d)
{
    int minor = iminor(file_inode(f));
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to Marco Bonelli's answer, `file_inode()` was added in the 3.9 kernel, so if earlier kernel versions need to be supported, some kernel compatibility code needs to be added. I use something like the following:

```
/*
 * The file_dentry() inline function was added in kernel version 4.6.0.
 * Emulate it for earlier kernels.
 */
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(4,6,0)
static inline struct dentry *kcompat_file_dentry(const struct file *f)
{
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,20)
    return f->f_dentry;
#else
    return f->f_path.dentry;
#endif
}
#undef file_dentry
#define file_dentry(f) kcompat_file_dentry(f)
#endif

/*
 * The file_inode() inline function was added in kernel 3.9.0.
 * Emulate it for earlier kernels.
 */
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(3,9,0)
static inline struct inode *kcompat_file_inode(struct file *f)
{
    return file_dentry(f)->d_inode;
}
#undef file_inode
#define file_inode(f)   kcompat_file_inode(f)
#endif
```